# コンソール入力を読み取る際、System.console() と System.in の違いは？

Tags: java

```
String s = System.console().readLine(); // 1

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine(); // 2
```

1と2の違いはなんなのでしょうか？
違いがある場合、それぞれのメリット、デメリットについても教えて頂けるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すでに挙げられているパスワードの入力非表示の他には、以下のような違いがあります。

- `Console`のメリット

  - コンソールのエンコーディングなどが自動的に設定される
  - 標準的なWindows環境のコマンドプロンプトで、以下の`ConsoleTest.java`を`UTF-8`で保存して実行し、例えば日本語を入力すると`2`の方法では、文字化けする
- `Console`のデメリット

  - `JDK 1.6.0`以降でのみ使用可能
  - `IDE`などで実行すると`JVM`に関連付けられているコンソール・デバイスが存在しない場合があり、`System.console()`が`null`で使用できない

```
> java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "." ConsoleTest
```

```
import java.io.*;
public class ConsoleTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console c = System.console();
    if (c != null) {
      String s = c.readLine("入力: "); // 1
      System.out.println("出力: " + s);
    }
    //else {
    System.out.println("----");

    //try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "MS932"))) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
      System.out.print("入力: ");
      String s = br.readLine(); // 2
      System.out.println("出力: " + s);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 補足、まことにありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

入力に対する読み取り機能そのものには差がないのですが、入力を隠す機能があります。

こちらの記事が参考になると思います。

http://www.javainthebox.net/laboratory/JavaSE6/console/console.html